# How to style select options with styled-components reactjs

Tags: reactjs, select, styled-components

I have problem with select options styling. I am able to change background and text color, but I can change size of dropdown. Maybe some could tell me what I am doing wrong?

My select:

```
<Select>
    <option value="" hidden>Type</option>
    <option value="1">Audi</option>
    <option value="2">BMW</option>
    <option value="3">Citroen</option>
    <option value="4">Ford</option>
 </Select>
```

My Styled-component:

```
const Select = styled.select`
  width: 100%;
  height:35px;
  background: white;
  color: gray;
  padding-left: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  border:none;
  margin-left: 10px;

       option {
         color: black;
         background: white;
         font-weight: small;
         display: flex;
         white-space: pre;
         min-height: 20px;
         padding: 0px 2px 1px;
       }
`;
```

How my select looks like:
[image: Select photo]

Comment: you forgot yo post demo to play with

Comment: Please clarify what part of the styling isn’t working. What is the desired look?

Comment: @RyanCogswell, I want that my option's width, font size would be same as select input.

Comment: This works fine for me: https://codesandbox.io/s/qk8r8l7w54. You have something else in your application that is impacting the option styling.

Comment: @RyanCogswell, I found out that it is not working on lower resolution.

Comment: Did You figure it out ? I also face the same issue with styling options

Answer (score 1):

The styles that you can give to an option element are the `background-color` and `color`. The other options are ignored. You can see more details in the question below.

[How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Comment: And even those styles may be browser dependent